# How can I get rid of the error message "Ambiguous use of internal linkage declaration '...' defined in multiple modules"

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

I have recently received hundreds of the following kind of error:

> Ambiguous use of internal linkage declaration 'DDLogFlagError' defined
>   in multiple modules

My podfile contains the following:

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by moving `"#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>"` 
to the top of my *xxx-Prefix.pc*h file. I then could remove some 
`"#import "CocoaLumberjack.h"` from my files.